# Android: Switch between Activities

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an audio player.

My first activity has a list of the mp3's from my sd card and I can choose some them and put them in an ArrayList.  I have a button (Add to playlist), and when I press it, it starts the new activity where I take the ArrayList, there I create my player, play music etc. But... when I press the back button on the device(you know this that look like such as a half-circled arrow), I go back to my first activity, but the music don't stop and I can choose again songs and if I press the Add To Playlist button then the app plays two songs simultaneously (my first and this second).

How can I handle this?  (I want when i go back, choose or unchoose some tracks and then when i press the button (Add to playlist) to play my new list).

I start my second activity like that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (Chooser.this, Player.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();    
b.putStringArrayList("key", plist);     
b.putStringArrayList("pos", po);           
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

---

I don't want my player stops, simply I want to add or remove songs in my playlist.

Comment: Tim - please don't use answers to communicate updates or further questions to other users. Either update your question or (when you reach the requisite amount of rep) add a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You want to implement the one of the [Android Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) methods in your second `Activity` and tell it to stop the `MediaPlayer`.

The ones you may be interested in are `onPause()`, `onStop()`, and `onDestroy()`.

Comment: Yes, thanks you very match, can you tell me where i can declare this global variable?And ,also i don't want my player stops, simply i want to add or remove songs in my playlist...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global variable to maintain the "is playing" state.  If you find the user tries to play a new song and the `isPlaying` variable is `true` then stop the player before starting the new song.